# How to enable site network in wordpress 4.9.7?

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I have setup wordpress 4.9.7 on my computer with mysql with the port number 81.
Now i need to enable multisite in wordpress.
I have modified

> wp-config.php

as follows

```
/* Multisite */
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost:81');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/silkstreet/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

and i have modified .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /silkstreet/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) C:/wamp64/www/SilkStreet/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ C:/wamp64/www/SilkStreet/$2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

and then i have created another site. all is good.

but when i visit the newly created site it redirect to primary site when i click on visit dashboard link of new site is shows

[image]

can anyone help on this?

Comment: These parts seem strange to me, why are they in there? `C:/wamp64/www/SilkStreet/$2` I checked multiple multi sites I manage and I never see anything like it in the `.htaccess`

Comment: but when i install multiple sites , wordpress navigate to a page and show mentioned code block to .htaccess file

Comment: Did you try removing the `C:/wamp64/www/SilkStreet/$2` part (but keeping the `[L]` part) ?

Comment: you mean like this 
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php) [L]

Comment: yes, my multisite `.htaccess` files look like that.

Comment: now error is gone. but still it redirect to primary site!

Comment: I actually see at a site of mine that the `$2` is still there. like this: `RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]`
     `RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177224/discussion-between-roshan-and-jrswgtr).